# Will calling Console.WriteLine() for a long running console application cause memory issues?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET Console application that runs for days and writes to its window using `Console.WriteLine()`.

I am concerned that this will ultimately cause a memory issue. Is that correct?

Assuming I want to write to the console window in this fashion is there something I can do to "clear" the console window buffer of messages and reduce memory consumption periodically?

Comment: A console application has a display buffer. Older lines will disappear from the buffer if you continue to add lines. To clear the console... `Console.Clear()`.

Comment: If you're concerned about memory issues, it would benefit you immensely to learn to use a *profiler* to locate those issues, rather than thinking each situation has a specific rule you need to learn.